# COM library Initialization failed with code 0x80010106 in C#

Tags: c#

I was trying to push data manually to NT using c# but i was getting an error as: "Failed to initialize COM library(0x80010106)."
I have already added the reference 'Ninjatrader.Client.dll'
I am posting my code as below:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading; 
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace read_file
{
 public static class Program
 {
    [DllImport("NtDirect.dll", EntryPoint = "Connected", SetLastError = true)]
    public extern static int Connected(int showMessage);

    [DllImport("NtDirect.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int Last(string instrument, double price, int size);

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        NinjaTrader.Client.Client NTClient = new NinjaTrader.Client.Client();
        int ConnectStatus = Connected(1);

        NTClient.Command("PLACE", "Sim101", "ES 03-08", "BUY", 1, "LIMIT", 1245.00, 0,   "GTC", "ax1234", "", "", "");
        int k;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            k = 10 * (i + 1);
            Last("AUDUSD", k, 4);
            for (int j = 0; j < 999999999; j++)
            {
            }
            Console.WriteLine(k);
                        }
        }
    }
 }
```

please tell me the correct suggestion.

Comment: See [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979113/qcroreapplication-qapplication-with-wmi)

Answer (score 18):

From the WinError.h SDK header file:

```
//
// MessageId: RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE
//
// MessageText:
//
// Cannot change thread mode after it is set.
//
#define RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE               _HRESULT_TYPEDEF_(0x80010106L)
```

This is a bug in the DLL you are using.  A DLL should *never* call CoInitializeEx() on a thread that it didn't create.  It is a fairly common bug however and there's little you can do about it.  But one thing, you'll have to initialize the apartment state of your thread so it matches the one that the DLL wants so the CoInitializeEx() call doesn't fail.

- If you make this call on your program's main thread then change the
  attribute on your Main() method.  Make it [STAThread] or [MTAThread],
  depending on what keeps the DLL happy.  Beware that this may be
  detrimental to your program, you must use [STAThread] if your program
  creates any windows or uses any other COM object that requires an STA.
- If you make this call on a Thread that you created then call the
  thread's SetApartmentState() method before you start it.
- If you make this call from a threadpool thread, such as those created
  by a BackgroundWorker or Task, a delegate's BeginInvoke method or the QueueUserWorkItem() method then you cannot change the apartment
  type, it is always MTA.  You'll have to create a Thread instead, see
  the previous bullet.

Also beware the apartment requirements.  If the DLL is only happy with an STA (likely) then you must pump a message loop with Application.Run().  Not doing so can cause deadlock or code internal to the component just doesn't run, this can be hard to diagnose.

Answer (score 2):

Set attribute `[STAThread]` to your class `Program`.

From my understanding, whenever you need COM objects that run on *STA (Single Thread Apartment)* you need to specify the `STAThreadAttribute` to your program.

You can *[learn more about the STAThreadAttribute from here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stathreadattribute.aspx)*...

Answer (score 0):

this can be for many reasons.
all of them are related to the fact the COM Factory cannot create your object.

i had a situation where i start a program and caught the same exception if it had 1 of the following:

1. License Validation failed
2. database backup notification popped up and delayed the load of the program.
3. Windows Server 2008R2 Prevented the App to show it's main window due to permission errors

What i am hinting is: Check what is preventing the NinjaTrader to load...
try checking the EventLogs or Application logs out...

might be permission issues, Etc.